# Ordering Queries in ormlite

Tags: java, android, ormlite

Why does

`where.or( where.eq(foo.name, name) ,  where.isNull(foo.name) );
where.and();
where.and( where.eq(foo.foreign_id, foreign_id) , where.ne(foo.deleted , true) );`

produce a different result set than

`where.and( where.eq(foo.foreign_id, foreign_id) , where.ne(foo.deleted , true) );
where.and();
where.or( where.eq(foo.name, name) ,  where.isNull(foo.name) );`

in OrmLite?